# Parallel computing memory access bottleneck

Tags: c++, multithreading, memory, optimization

The following algorithm is run iteratively in my program. running it, without the two lines indicated below, takes 1.5X as long as without. That is very surprising to me as it is. Worse, however, is that running *with* those two lines increases completion to 4.4X of running without them (6.6X not running whole algorithm). Additionaly, it causes my program to fail to scale beyond ~8 cores. In fact, when run on a single core, the two lines only increase time to 1.7x, which is still way too high considering what they do. I've ruled out that it has to do with an effect of the modified data elsewhere in my program.

So I'm wondering what could be causing this. Something to do with the cache maybe?

```
void NetClass::Age_Increment(vector <synapse> & synapses, int k)  
{
    int size = synapses.size();
    int target = -1;

    if(k > -1)
    {
        for(int q=0, x=0 ; q < size; q++)
        {
            if(synapses[q].active)
                synapses[q].age++;
            else
            {
                if(x==k)target=q;
                x++;
            }
        }
        /////////////////////////////////////Causing Bottleneck/////////////
        synapses[target].active = true;
        synapses[target].weight = .04 + (float (rand_r(seedp) % 17) / 100);
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    }

    else
    {
        for(int q=0 ; q < size; q++)
            if(synapses[q].active)
                synapses[q].age++;
    }
}
```

**Update:** Changing the two problem lines to:

```
bool x = true;
float y = .04 + (float (rand_r(seedp) % 17) / 100);
```

Removes the problem. Suggesting maybe that it's something to do with memory access?

Comment: @Mankarse What is the likely cause of this, how can it make sense?

Comment: @GMan it does the same thing as `rand()`. I call it much more frequently elsewhere. I think its defined in `<csdtlib>`. I'll test to make sure its not the issue.

Comment: @MattMunson: `rand` is part of `<cstdlib>`, but I've never heard of `rand_r`. Googling, it appears to be a Linux extension. (And a good one at that, removing global state.) Is `seedp` shared? What happens if you replace `rand_r(seedp)` with `0`, for example?

Comment: @GMan replacing `rand_r()` altogether with a constant didn't help.

Comment: @GMan From what I can tell `rand_r` is a POSIX function that was added in 2001 and removed from the standard in 2008.

Comment: @GMan a struct with 1 `bool` 2 `int` 2 `float`, a constructor, and a small reset function.

Comment: @MattMunson: Sorry, I meant to ask how many elements exist in the `vector`? Is it huge?

Comment: @GMan Oh, my bad. The function is called 4 times per iteration, size is 72, 36, 8, and 3 respectively for the 4 different calls.

Comment: Does the problem go away if you change `synapses[target]` to `synapses[size - 1]`? (Obviously disregarding correctness.)

Comment: @GMan  no, it doesn't go away. However, setting the first line to `= false` is making it go away, so I fear I've made a great mis-calculation.

Comment: @MattMunson: Interesting. I'm out of ideas as to what it could be (your vectors are small enough that cache isn't an issue), the only thing left is to make sure your concurrency is being performed correctly and your algorithm is running as specified.

Comment: @GMan Sorry to lead you on a bit of a goose chase. It turns out this algorithm was not the problem, but rather its the main computation algorithm (failing to scale). Would you care to take a look if you have time?

Comment: @MattMunson: Perhaps, sure, though the time I spend on SO is already time I shouldn't be spend here. :) (In other words, yes, but it would be quite on the side and suspect to unspecified delay.)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5385/discussion-between-matt-munson-and-gman)

Comment: @GMan Cool. I will post the code in chat and we can discuss it to your convenience.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Each thread modifies memory all the other reads read:

```
for(int q=0, x=0 ; q < size; q++)
   if(synapses[q].active) ... // ALL threads read EVERY synapse.active
...
synapses[target].active = true; // EVERY thread writes at leas one synapse.active
```

These kind of reads and writes on the same address from different threads cause a great deal of cache invalidation, which will result in exactly the symptoms you describe. The solution is to avoid the write inside the loop, and the fact that moving the write into local variables is, again, proof that the problem is cache invalidation. Note that even if you wouldn't write the sane field being read (`active`), you would likely see the same symptoms due to false sharing, as I suspect that `active`, `age` and `weight` share a cache line.

For more details see [CPU Caches and Why You Care](http://www.aristeia.com/TalkNotes/ACCU2011_CPUCaches.pdf)

A final note is that the assignment to `active` and `weight`, not to mention the `age++`increment all seem extremely thread unsafe. Interlocked operations or lock/mutex protection for such updates would be mandatory.

Comment: Cool. But btw `synapse` objects are not shared between threads.

Answer (score 2):

If `size` is relatively small it doesn't surprise me at all that a call to a PRNG, an integer division, and a float division and addition would increase program execution that much. You're doing a fair amount of work so it seems logical that it would increase the runtime. Additionally since you told the compiler to do the math as `float` rather than `double` that could increase time even further on some systems (where native floating point is double). Have you considered a fixed point representation with `int`s?

I can't say why it would scale worse with more cores, unless you exceed the number of cores your program has been given by the OS (or if your system's `rand_r` is implemented using locking or thread-specific data to maintain additional state).

Also note that you never check if `target` is valid before using it as an array index, if it ever makes it out of the `for` loop still set to -1 all bets are off for your program.

Comment: I do much more arithmetic elsewhere in the program. Also, I'm not exceeding the cores and removing rand_r did not improve anything.

Answer (score 2):

Try re-introducing these two lines, but without `rand_r`, just to see if you get the same performance deterioration. If you don't, this is probably a sign that the `rand_r` is internally serialized (e.g. through a mutex), so you'd need to find a way to generate random numbers more concurrently.

The other potential area of concern is [false sharing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_sharing) (if you have time, take a look at Herb Sutter's [video](http://video.google.com/videoplay?docid=-4714369049736584770) and [slides](http://www.nwcpp.org/Downloads/2007/Machine_Architecture_-_NWCPP.pdf) treating this subject, among others). Essentially, if your threads happen to modify different memory locations that are close enough to fall into the same cache line, the cache coherency hardware may effectively serialize the memory access and destroy the scalability. What makes this hard to diagnose is the fact that these memory locations may be *logically* independent and it may not be intuitively obvious they ended up close together at run-time. Try adding some padding to split such memory locations apart if you suspect false sharing.

Comment: What I usually do is add a [cache-line] size buffer as the first private data member of each object. Setting it to zero in the c'tor is usually enough to prevent it being optimized away.  Some languages/libs, (boost, AFAIK), allow precise control over object placement and that should be even better - With large objects, having the instance data start on a page boundary, and then fill up pagesize-multiples, would be nice!

Comment: @Martin Well when it comes to the set of objects I'm working with, I make a thread-local copy of each object for working on and then put that back into the process-local vector when I'm done with it. If there's any false sharing I would think that it's with arrays from member vectors (from the objects) that happen to be allocated near each other (if that makes sense?). Is there anything to do about that?